# Perl Datetime::Format::ISO8601 issue

Tags: perl, datetime

I am confused on why this is giving me the "Invalid date format:  2021-09-10"
here is my code:

```
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Span;
use Datetime::Format::ISO8601;
open(FH_Comp, "<", "C:\\Perl_Scripts\\Stock_List_COMPARE.txt") or die("Cannot open Stock_List_COMPARE.txt: $!\n"); 
my @lines = <FH_Comp>; 
close(FH_Comp);

open(FH_CompRev, "<", "C:\\Perl_Scripts\\Stock_List_Rev.txt") or die("Cannot open Stock_List_Rev.txt: $!\n"); 
my @compRev = <FH_CompRev>; 
close(FH_CompRev);
    
my $iso8601 = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->new;

foreach $lines (@lines) {
    @COMPlist = split(",",$lines);
    foreach $compRev (@compRev) {       
        @REVlist = split(",",$compRev);
        my $dt_set = DateTime::Span->from_datetimes(
            start  => $iso8601->parse_datetime($REVlist[0]),
            before => $iso8601->parse_datetime($REVlist[4]),
        );          
        if ( $dt_set->contains( $iso8601->parse_datetime($COMPlist[0]) ) ) {    
            print "Within date range\n";
            $Total1 = $COMPlist[2] + $REVlist[2];
            print "ADJ Date is '$COMPlist[0]' => $COMPlist[2] + $REVlist[2] = " . $Total1 . " ! '$REVlist[0]' or '$REVlist[4]'";        
        }
        else {
            print "Not within date range\n";
        }           
    }
}
```

Here is what Stock_List_COMPARE.txt looks like:

```
2016-06-30, 00354                          , 1.00000, 38.62000
2016-06-30, 00354                          , 24.00000, 38.62000
```

Here is what the Stock_List_Rev.txt look like:

```
2021-09-10,  00354                         , 1.00000, 44.44000, 2021-09-10
2021-08-27,  00354                         , 2.00000, 44.24000, 2021-09-10
```

The odd thing is why does it work if it is hard coded as appose to getting it from my files (see below code):

```
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Span;
use Datetime::Format::ISO8601;
    my $iso8601t = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->new;
    my $first = "2020-12-10"; 
    my $last = "2021-09-10";
    #chomp $last;
    my $dt_set = DateTime::Span->from_datetimes(
        start  => $iso8601t->parse_datetime($first),
        before => $iso8601t->parse_datetime($last),
    );
    if ( $dt_set->contains( $iso8601t->parse_datetime("2021-04-10") ) ) {   
        print "Within date range\n";
    }
    else {
        print "Not within date range\n";
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could it be the leading space? Have you tried trimming the fields?

Comment: You problem is within `split()`, change to `split('[,\s]+',$compRev)`.

Comment: Note: wouldn't it be more wise to use a variables to store file names?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the corrected code, OP's problem is that dates are not *sanitized* and includes spaces and new line.

Function [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split) takes separator in very *flexible form* of regular expression what is very helpful in such situations

NOTE:

- OP must start the code with `use strict;` and `use warnings;` otherwise some undesired behavior may crepe in
- OP declares some variables with `my $variable;` but other variables does not -- there is a significant chance that somewhere in the code he/she will redefine a variable in local scope what would lead to unexpected behavior

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime;
use DateTime::Span;
use Datetime::Format::ISO8601;

my $fn_compare = 'C:\Perl_Scripts\Stock_List_COMPARE.txt';
my $fn_rev     = 'C:\Perl_Scripts\Stock_List_Rev.txt';

open(FH_Comp, "<", $fn_compare) or die("Cannot open $fn_compare: $!"); 
my @lines = <FH_Comp>; 
close(FH_Comp);

open(FH_CompRev, "<", $fn_rev) or die("Cannot open $fn_rev: $!"); 
my @compRev = <FH_CompRev>; 
close(FH_CompRev);
    
my $iso8601 = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->new;

foreach my $line (@lines) {
    my @COMPlist = split('[,\s]+',$line);
    foreach my $compRev (@compRev) {       
        my @REVlist = split('[,\s]+',$compRev);
        my $dt_set = DateTime::Span->from_datetimes(
            start  => $iso8601->parse_datetime($REVlist[0]),
            before => $iso8601->parse_datetime($REVlist[4]),
        );          
        if ( $dt_set->contains( $iso8601->parse_datetime($COMPlist[0]) ) ) {    
            print "Within date range\n";
            my $Total1 = $COMPlist[2] + $REVlist[2];
            print "ADJ Date is '$COMPlist[0]' => $COMPlist[2] + $REVlist[2] = " . $Total1 . " ! '$REVlist[0]' or '$REVlist[4]'";        
        }
        else {
            print "Not within date range\n";
        }           
    }
}
```

Output

```
Not within date range
Not within date range
Not within date range
Not within date range
```

NOTE: perhaps OP could use `my($var_1,$var_2,$var_3,$var_4) = split('[,\s]+',$line);` to assign more meaningful variable names to make the code more readable and easier to maintain

NOTE: please see if following code style makes sense to you

```
        if ( $dt_set->contains( $iso8601->parse_datetime($COMPlist[0]) ) ) {    
            print "Within date range\n";
            printf "ADJ Date is %s => %s + %s = %s ! %s or %s\n",
                   $COMPlist[0],
                   $COMPlist[2],
                   $REVlist[2],
                   $COMPlist[2] + $REVlist[2],
                   $REVlist[0],
                   $REVlist[4];        
        } else {
            print "Not within date range\n";
        }
```

NOTE: `print "$var\n";` can be replaced with `say $var;` -- add line `use feature 'say';` at top of the code file

Reference: [say](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say)

Comment: I would use `split(/\s*,\s*/, $line)`. The comma is the required field separator. The spaces are inconsequential. `[,\s]+` might incorrectly split on a single space inside of a field.

Comment: Perhaps you should check how `split` works and what `split('[,\s,]+`,$var)` will do.

Comment: I know exactly how it works, and I stand by comment. I didn't say your version wouldn't work, just that it could be improved.